# Call a login feature from test feature

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, karate, ui-automation

I am trying to login to my application using a common feature file. I cannot get this to work. I am not able to run any commands after my common feature file runs.

I get an error like this:
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "waitForEnabled" is not defined

Here is an example of my feature file:

```
    Feature: Transaction Admin

    Background:
        # Transaction Admin Page
        * def parameters = read('configs.json')
        * def test = read('Login.feature@login-chrome')
        
    @transactionadmin-workflow-updatename
    @test
    Scenario: Search
        # Open Transaction Admin Page
        * test.waitForEnabled(administrationButtonXpath).click()
        And delay(2000).screenshot()
```

I am trying to call my 'Login.feature' file which will set the driver and login to my application. That runs successfully but the next step that tries to run always fails. In this case it is 'waitForEnabled'.

I have been looking at the documentation and I am not sure what I am missing.
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#code-reuse
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/call-updates-config.feature
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#shared-scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was not having my 2nd file refer to another file. I guess three levels deep is too deep...

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your feature file like below:

```
Feature: Transaction Admin

    Background:
        # Transaction Admin Page
        * def parameters = read('configs.json')
        * call read('Login.feature')
        
    @transactionadmin-workflow-updatename
    @test
    Scenario: Search
        # Open Transaction Admin Page
        * waitForEnabled(administrationButtonXpath).click()
        And delay(2000).screenshot()
```

Also I tried with swag labs and it was working. I created 2 feature files under src/test/java under com.tests package

Login.feature

```
Feature: Login code reuse feature

  Scenario: Login code reuse scenario
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }
    * driver 'https://www.saucedemo.com/'
    * input('input[id=user-name]', 'standard_user')
    * input('input[id=password]', 'secret_sauce')
    * click('input[id=login-button]')
```

Home.feature

```
Feature: Home Page feature

  Background: 
    * call read('Login.feature')

  Scenario: Home Page scenario
    
    * waitForEnabled('button[id=react-burger-menu-btn]').click()
    * delay(3000)
```

Html report
[image]

Comment: Thank you @cyrilgeorge153 but that still does not work for me...

I get this error:
```
13:52:47.299 TransactionAdmin.Workflow.UpdateName.feature:25
* waitForEnabled(administrationButtonXpath).click()
js failed:
>>>>
01: waitForEnabled(administrationButtonXpath).click()
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "waitForEnabled" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

TransactionAdmin.Workflow.UpdateName.feature:25
```

Comment: @joshKDev Please find the recommended folder hierarchy from this link: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#naming-conventions. I have shared the answer assuming that you are following same folder structure. Above answer will work definitely if you follow the recommended folder hierarchy.